# How do I fix material-yew use declaration?

Tags: rust, webassembly, yew

I tried to do a hello world with [material-yew](https://crates.io/crates/material-yew).

I tried to add this use declaration according to Material Yew's home page.

```
use material_yew::MatButton;
```

I've also tried this version that I've also seen in the docs:

```
use material_yew::button::MatButton;
```

But both of them give a similar error:

> error[E0432]: unresolved import `material_yew::MatButton`

I have these in my Cargo.toml:

```
[dependencies]
yew = "0.19.3"
material-yew = "0.2.0"
```

And I'm using `trunk serve` to run the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable the `button` feature (or the `full` feature that implies it):

```ini
material-yew = { version = "0.2.0", features = ["button"] }
```